# License Plate Statistics

Tags: statistics, puzzle, cryptography

California issues license plates in numeric order (if we turn the letters into numbers).  I have fun noticing the latest plate I have seen.  I am interested in what you can derive from a series of these observations.  I understand that sampling from $\{1,2,3...n\}$ the only useful data is the highest value you have seen.

Let's oversimplify the problem.  Assume the highest plate issued is $N_0+n*t$, $n$ in plates/day and $t$ in days.  Assume a similar number of low valued plates come off the road each day.  I don't observe a consistent number of plates each day, but it averages out.  Over a long time, the increase in highest plate seen should give a measure of $n$.  The only other data I have is how frequently I see a new highest plate.  Does that give some measure of how far my highest plate is from the highest issued?

As we are asked to cite the source of a question, I made it up.  You probably guessed.

Comment: Are you familiar with the German Tank Problem?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem

Comment: No, I wasn't.  Thanks

Comment: An [original], [original-problem], [homegrown] or other such tag would be nice for these things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joseph Gallian has decrypted many of the US state license plate and driver's license codes.

http://books.google.com/books?id=PD0clAlF8O4C&pg=PA27

I think he used Markov chain models.  As whuber mentioned your problem is similar to the German tanks for which the subject reference is "extreme value statistics".