# How to estimate total population size given a small numbered selection from that population?

Tags: probability

So let's say you find a small amount of numbered collectibles (e.g. 3 collectibles numbered 5, 14 and 103). Is there a way to estimate the total number of collectibles in existence?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704828/determining-total-number-of-tickets-sold and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762959/estimating-parameter-of-random-sample and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6648/license-plate-statistics and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455931/german-tank-problem-simple-derivation and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65398/why-does-this-expected-value-simplify-as-shown and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3002437/sum-of-reciprocal-numbers-of-combinations and surely many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "German Tank Problem", addressed [here](https://what-if.xkcd.com/65/) and [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) among other places; see Ruggles, R.; Brodie, H. (1947). "An Empirical Approach to Economic Intelligence in World War II". *Journal of the American Statistical Association* 42 (237): 72 for the  real scoop. In war time serial numbers on  captured enemy equipment gives a clue about how many units might exist.

You can find other MSE postings by searching for "German Tank Problem".

The recipe is explained in the last two citations above.

Of historical or antiquarian interest, perhaps better suited to the history of science and mathematics SE:  This problem is also known as the "Taxi" problem, and before that the "Trolley Car Problem", and
some notables who were interested in it were Alan Turing, M.H.A. Newman, R.A. Fisher.  It seems to have been first formulated as a math problem by Erwin Schroedinger.

Comment: Closely related: [capture-recapture method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture).

Comment: @TobyMak  Yes.  The Tank problem is easier than the problem the C-R method solves because of the serial numbers.